# Is there an equivalent of app.config in appjs?

Tags: c#, app-config, appjs

I'm searching an equivalent of app.config for appjs because I need to store some variables and I don't want that an user can see one of them. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

the app.config file is in server side but the .js run in client side. there is no file such as app.config
you should use client side solutions like cookies or you can save your variable on server and then load that with ajax when you need it.